# Problems connecting an existing php interface to an existing SQL Server DB - odbc error

Tags: php, sql, odbc

I am having enormous trouble connecting an existing (not programmed by myself) PHP interface to an existing SQL Server DB. I have been accessing a copy of this SQL Server DB for testing purposes on my local machine from my own self-programmed PHP interface using odbc "system DSN" interfaces. But probably, the odbc interface on my local testing environment will be looking different than on the real server, I guess.

I am establishing the odbc connection using code that looks like this:

```
$db_server ="localhost"; 
$db_name  ="testdb"; 
$db_user    ="testuser";   
$db_pass    ="test";

$conn = odbc_connect($db_name, $db_user, $db_pass) or die ('Can not connect '. $db_name);
```

This works fine - I can access the db and everything works as it should.

The PHP interface that I am trying to integrate in my testing environment does the connection this way:

```
$db_server = "localhost"; # I changed that one from the original server name
$db_user   = "testuser";
$db_pass   = "test";
$db_name   = "testdb";
$connection_id = odbc_connect($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

So it seems the connection on the server is done without mentioning the $db_name field. Sounds strange to me, but I am only a novice concerning SQL via odbc - normally I only use MySQL.

So when the PHP code tries accessing the db, the following error occurs:

> Warning: odbc_connect()
>   [function.odbc-connect]: SQL error:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data
>   source name not found and no default
>   driver specified, SQL state IM002 in
>   SQLConnect in
>   D:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\testdb\global.include
>   on line xxx
>
> xxx is the line containing
>   "$connection_id =
>   odbc_connect($dbserver, $dbuser,
>   $dbpass); "

Any ideas how to get that thing working? I am nearly absolutely sure it's got something to do with the odbc datainterfaces defined on my machine, but I have no idea right now.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Thanks,
Sasha

Comment: Your second snippet initialises $db_server etc and then uses $dbserver-- is that right?

Answer (score 2):

When you connect via ODBC, you don't actually specify the target details of the database, you specify a data source name. This data source name is looked up in the data source registry, and the connection details are obtained from there. So you need to set $db_server to be the data source name, not the actual host name.

Comment: Hi araqnid,

thanks a billion! That was what confused me that much! Aaaargh, so much wasted time and such a simple and idiotic mistake - just as always...

Solved.

Comment: @Sasha - If this answer solved your problem, consider marking it as accepted and providing an up vote. It not only thanks @araqnid, but also shows the community that the answer was valuable in the context of your problem.

Comment: I just figured out that you have to specify a SYSTEM datasource and not a user datasource. Took me an hour to figure that one out.